# How can I find the database I created for my Rails application locally and load it to a server?

Tags: mysql, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Lynda.com Rails tutorial. I created a MySQL database for my Ruby on Rails application simple_cms.

The database is called simple_cms_development.

Let's say I want to move this database into a new server, where do I find it?

I am running rvm, and I saw mysql is inside this rvm, but I am not able to access it. I searched my computer for simple_cms_development , and couldn't find anything either. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: use mysql workbeanch to extract the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Copy the source code from the **original** machine to the **new** machine, or get it onto your **new** machine from a remote repository using git.
2. Run `rake:db:create` in the application directory on your **new** machine.  This is assuming you have MySQL running on the **new** machine.
3. Use either the `mysql` client or the `mysqldump` utility to get a dump file of your MySQL database from your **original** machine.
4. Copy the dump file to the **new** machine and load it into the database using the MySQL client.

You can google the details of how to use git, dump and load MySQL, etc.

RVM is a tool for **m**anaging **R**uby **v**ersions and gems.  A Rails project backed by a MySQL database will need to use some Ruby gem (like `mysql2`) to allow the Rails app to talk to the MySQL database.  All you're seeing in the `.rvm` directory is the gem.  I'm not sure if the usual MySQL gems provide functionality to dump or load a database, at any rate you may as well use the MySQL client directly.